# Is there any way to escape dot in path Json1 Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-json1

It seems that if I have key `test1.test2` there is no way to escape this dot to use this key as is.

Expression:

```
sqlite> update collections set json_nodes = (select json_set(json(collections.js
on_nodes), '$.test.test1', json('123')) from collections);
```

will lead to

```
{"test":{"test1":123}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, why do you have this constelation?

Comment: Did you try backslash?

Comment: `update collections set json_nodes = (select json_set(json(collections.js
on_nodes), '$."test.test1"', json('123')) from collections);` or **'`$.test.test1]'`**

Answer (score 1):

For lookup, you can enclose the key name that contains a dot in double quotes.  However, if your key name contains a double quote, I think you are out-of-luck unless you modify the source code to the JSON1 extension.

Escaping by double quote seems to be not documented, but you can see the way it works from [the source code to the JSON1 extension](https://www.sqlite.org/src/file/ext/misc/json1.c), in the function `jsonLookupStep`.

Example:

```
SELECT json_extract(json_data, '$."Issuer.LongCompanyName"')
FROM instruments_table
```